# Loading heroku pg database with scraped data from scrapy spider.\

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, scrapy, heroku-postgres

I am news to heroku pg. What I am doing here is I have written a scrapy crawler which runs without any errors. Problem is I want to put all the scraped data into my heroku postgres database. For doing that I somewhat followed [this tutorial](http://newcoder.io/scrape/part-1/)

When I run crawler on my local machne using `scrapy crawl spidername` it runs successfull but scraped data is not inserted neither any table is created on heroku database. I dont even get any errors on local terminal. this is what my code is...

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'crawlerconnectdatabase'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['crawlerconnectdatabase.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'crawlerconnectdatabase.spiders'

DATABASE = {'drivername': 'postgres',
        'host': 'ec2-54-235-250-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
        'port': '5432',
        'username': 'dtxwjcycsaweyu',
        'password': '***',
        'database': 'ddcir2p1u2vk07'}
```

**items.py**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class CrawlerconnectdatabaseItem(Item):
    name = Field()
    url = Field()
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    page_title = Field()
    desc_link = Field()
    body = Field()
    news_headline = Field()
    pass
```

**models.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
import settings

DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()


def db_connect():

    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))


def create_deals_table(engine):

    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)


class Deals(DeclarativeBase):
"""Sqlalchemy deals model"""
    __tablename__ = "news_data"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = Column('body', String)
```

**pipelines.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Deals, db_connect, create_deals_table

class CrawlerconnectdatabasePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        engine = db_connect()
        create_deals_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        session = self.Session()
        deal = Deals(**item)

        try:
            session.add(deal)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()

        return item
```

**spider**

code for scrapy spider you will find it [here](http://pastebin.com/9kt0ebiM)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the ITEM_PIPELINES = {'crawlerconnectdatabase.pipelines.CrawlerconnectdatabasePipeline': 300,} to your settings.py